# How to make a turn based game loop in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am working on a game on Python and now I need to make a game loop in which a random person is selected to go first and their turn is executed.

My code so far is:

while health > 0 and health1 > 0:

```
    if turn == 1:
            while loopx == False:
                    try:
                            move = raw_input("Do you want to attack or gegenerate health? Press 1 to ATTACK and 2 to REGEN. ")
                            print ""
                            move = int(move)
                            if move == 1:
                                    health1 = health1 - damage
                                    print "You attacked!"
                                    loopx == True
                            elif move == 2:
                                    health = health+regen
                                    print "You regenerated health!"
                                    loopx = True
                            else:
                                    print "Invalid number, try again"
                                    continue
                    except:
                                    print "Invalid number, try again"
                                    continue
            turn == 2

    if turn == 2:
            AImove = r.randint(1,2)
            if AImove == 1:
                    print "AI attacked!"
                    health = health - damage1
            else:
                    print "AI regenerated!"
                    health1 = health1+regen1
            turn == 1
            continue
```

print "game over!"

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: when you are entering/editing your comment or question there is a symbol that look like two brackets { }  if you select your codeand press that it will format the code for you

Comment: {turn = r.randint(1,2)
win = False
print ""
while win == False:
        if turn == 1:
                print "You are going first!"
        else:
                print "A.I is starting."}

Comment: code doesnt post well in comments, suggest you edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Ok, now i stated ,my code in the question.

Comment: Okay, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: im not sure yet... i'm just confused about how to make a turn-based game loop

Comment: "im not sure yet" Then why are you here?

Comment: i cant paste the whole code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious problem I see with your code is that you're often doing asignment wrong. You're using the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator. The former checks for equality, rather than doing an assignment.

Here's your code with this issue fixed (see comments for fix locations):

```
while health > 0 and health1 > 0:

    if turn == 1:
            while loopx == False:
                    try:
                            move = raw_input("Do you want to attack or gegenerate health? Press 1 to ATTACK and 2 to REGEN. ")
                            print ""
                            move = int(move)
                            if move == 1:
                                    health1 = health1 - damage
                                    print "You attacked!"
                                    loopx = True                        # fix1
                            elif move == 2:
                                    health = health+regen
                                    print "You regenerated health!"
                                    loopx = True
                            else:
                                    print "Invalid number, try again"
                                    continue
                    except:
                                    print "Invalid number, try again"
                                    continue
            turn = 2                                                    # fix 2

    if turn == 2:
            AImove = r.randint(1,2)
            if AImove == 1:
                    print "AI attacked!"
                    health = health - damage1
            else:
                    print "AI regenerated!"
                    health1 = health1+regen1
            turn = 1                                                    # fix 3
            continue

print "game over!"
```

Comment: thanks! this might seem unrelated but do you know how to compile python scripts?